# after update mac os to catalina ,I have some problem android studio and Xcode is not simulator (Flutter)

Tags: xcode, android-studio, flutter, dart

Android

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script '/Users/admin/Documents/flutterpath/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 896
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command '/Users/admin/Documents/flutterpath/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 54s

XCODE Error : Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
I already try to fix lock and unlock keychain.

Comment: Did you set your flutter SDK path using the terminal in macOS?

Comment: Yes I set sdk path .

Comment: Still getting error ?